# Почему в 31 строке пишет что не определены индентификаторы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

float numbers(double x, double b, double c)
{
    cout<<"Input x = ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Input b = ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << " Input c = ";
    cin >> c;

    float y;
    y = ((2 * x - c) / sqrt(x - b)) + fabs(x - b);

    cout << "Answer is " << y;

    return y;   
}

int main()
{
    int result;
    
    do {
        
        result = numbers(x, b, c);

        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "b = " << b << endl;
        cout << "c = " << c << endl;
        
        

    } while (result <= 0);
    
}
```

Comment: Сидеть и считать строки? Что, так тяжело ее выделить хотя бы комментарием? Или — чай, не графья, посчитаете!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что они не определены.

```
result = numbers(x, b, c);
```

Что такое здесь `x`, `b`, `c`? Чему они равны? Какой тип имеют?

Объявление

```
float numbers(double x, double b, double c)
```

действует только внутри функции, это аргументы функции. Вне ее эти `x`, `b`, `c` никакого смысла не имеют.

И еще... даже допустив, что это не так, переданные по значеню аргументы при выходе из функции не меняются, так что введенные в функции значения `x` никак не могут быть выведены в `cout` вне ее...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

double numbers(double &x, double &b, double &c)  /// <<< передача по ссылке!!!
{
    cout<<"Input x = ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Input b = ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << " Input c = ";
    cin >> c;

    double y;       /// Используйте везде один тип - или float или double
    y = ((2 * x - c) / sqrt(x - b)) + fabs(x - b);

    cout << "Answer is " << y;

    return y;   
}

int main()
{
    double result;        /// <<<  float/double, не int!!!
    
    do {

        double x, b, c;   /// Объявление переменных     

        result = numbers(x, b, c);

        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "b = " << b << endl;
        cout << "c = " << c << endl;
        
        

    } while (result <= 0);
    
}
```

Comment: Это переменные, их значение пользователь вводит с клавиатуры, они имеют тип double

Comment: Только внутри функции! Но не вне ее. Чему они равны *в момент вызова*?

Comment: А как их определить? Я хочу чтобы эти переменные из функции numbers выводились в цикле do while

Comment: Написал исправленную программу в ответе. Странно, `result` вы сами объявить могли, а `x`, `b`, `c` - нет?

Comment: Спасибо огромное